# Browser Window in each method of test case? Using coded ui

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am new to coded UI, is it good practice to initialize Browser Window in each method of test case. For example i have two methods in my test case, I am trying to find control in each method, for that i write browser window in each method, can i write like that.

Comment: BrowserWindow br= new BrowserWindow(); br.SearchProper.Add(xxx);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an issue with that approach.

**Are you trying to reduce code/setup statements?**

It really depends, you could have a test class with many test methods. however have a method attributed with `ClassInitialize` to launch the browser one time (and set the option to not destroy the window after each test) and keep reusing the same window. Then, possibly, have a method to close the window attributed with `ClassCleanup`.

Then in a test, you should only potentially need to use the `NavigateTo` method at the start of your tests to be on the right page.

**Do you have test requirements dealing with sessions or saved data?**

You may need to actively close down a window after a test and programmatically empty caches. Then in this aspect, I would be using `BrowserWindow.Launch` typically and letting `CodedUi` automatically destroy the window if i forgot to call close on the window.